# Android MediaCodec + Surfaceview not smooth

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-mediacodec

I am going to play a video decoded by MediaCodec. The video was successfully decoded but what displayed in the SurfaceView was awful:

[image]

[image]

I have no idea how to fix it

Here is the player thread's code:

http://codepad.org/7JkQ6wfQ

In the main thread, i simply instance the player thread class and call the start function in the surfacechanged function of the SurfaceView's callback(SurfaceHolder.Callback)

Comment: What format is the video in?  Are you able to play the video file with the device's media player?

Comment: I'd only test .mp4 and .ts format, and they both failed on the player above but played well on my device's media player

Comment: It looks like corrupted video or a codec problem, not an issue with SurfaceView, but I don't see anything obviously wrong.  You can try the player in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika) and, if that works, trace through and see what it's doing differently.

Comment: @shockwave Did you solve the problem yet? I am facing almost same problem :)